# jquery unbind() in legacy webforms with masterpage

Tags: jquery, webforms, master-pages, unbind

I have added various jquery functions to a legacy webforms app that has a master page and user controls.

One of these jquery functions is to handle the onclick event of the main menu that is located on the master page.

The JQuery function to handle the onclick event of the menu is also in the master page:

```
$(function() {
        $('#iMenu').click(function(event) {
           // transfer to the page selected in the menu 
           . . . 
        });
      });
```

Everything has been working fine.

But now I need to do a validity check before the menu onclick processing occurs on one of the content pages. I can get the validity check to run, but I can't get the app to stay on the same page.

I tried disconnecting the function using

```
         $(function() {   
           $('#iMenu').unbind("click");
         });
```

on the content page but it did not stop the function from being called from the master page, and transferring away from the page where the validity check failed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: "jqueryScripts/jquery-1.4.js"  , 
 "jqueryScripts/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"